# To arrive on/with/??? flight

Tags: word-usage

How to say it correctly?

They will arrive with flight number 123 in London.
They will arrive on flight number 123 in London.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is correct since they are part of the flight **on** the airplane so they would. They are not arriving alongside the airplane. ‘They’ and the airplane are treated as 1 entity.